# What is the best way to apply a function to a subset of a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, rcpp

Say I have a `vector<int> positions` that represents positions that I would like to subset from, and two `Rcpp::NumericVector` vectors `A` and `B` that I want to subset (both can be treated also as `vector<double>`).

What would be the best way to calculate what in `R` I would write as 
`sum(A[positions])` (a `double`), or `A[positions] / B[positions]` (a `vector[double]`)? 
Basically, I would like to access the elements of the vectors at certain positions without making copies (or a `for` loop) if I do not have to.

Example in `R`:

```
positions = c(2,4,5) # just a vector with positions
A = rnorm(100) # a vector with 100 random numbers
B = rnorm(100)

mysum <- sum(A[positions])
mysmallvector <- A[positions] / B[positions] # or (A/B)[positions]
```

Right now I just loop through all the values of `positions` and and subset the vectors by position one by one, but I can't help thinking there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: Avoiding a for loop is not possible: you have to iterate through your collections. This is also what R does behind the scenes. If on the other hand, you want a more elegant API, I'm afraid you will need to resort to writing your own classes or use some C++ matrix library of which there are plenty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, replicating R's functionality in Rcpp is not necessarily ideal. For one, you should definitely check out the caveats to [subsetting in Rcpp](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/subsetting/) using Rcpp sugar expressions. Secondly, you are using a `for` loop even within R due to the vectorization structure R has.

You may wish to consider using [RcppArmadillo](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppArmadillo/index.html) instead of Rcpp data types. The downside to this is you will incur a copy hit when the data is ported into C++ and then back to R. With Rcpp data types, you will avoid that but you will have to define your own operations (see **divide_subset()** below).

With this being said, we can replicate the functionality requested via Rcpp:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// Uses sugar index subsets
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector subset(NumericVector x, IntegerVector idx) {
  return x[idx];
}

// Uses sugar summation function (e.g. a nice for loop)
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double sum_subset(NumericVector x, IntegerVector idx) {
  return sum(subset(x,idx));
}

// No sugar for element-wise division
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector divide_subset(NumericVector x, NumericVector y, IntegerVector idx) {
  unsigned int n = idx.size();
  NumericVector a(n);
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < idx.size(); i++){
    a[i] = x[idx[i]]/y[idx[i]];
  }

  return a;
}


/*** R
set.seed(1334)
positions = c(2,4,5) 

# Subtract one from indexes for C++
pos_cpp = positions - 1

A = rnorm(100) # a vector with 100 random numbers
B = rnorm(100)

mysum = sum(A[positions])

cppsum = sum_subset(A, pos_cpp)
all.equal(cppsum, mysum)

mysmallvector = A[positions] / B[positions] # or (A/B)[positions]

cppdivide = divide_subset(A,B, pos_cpp)
all.equal(cppdivide, mysmallvector)
*/
```